# What is the use of folders inside a Solution or Project (in Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directory, organization

I've been messing around with some public and work Git repos (all Github), as I grow my burgeoning C# expertise...

Especially for tutorial and course repos, they use a lot of folders. I also noticed you can add a "Solution Folder". However, I've also noticed Visual Studio has this love-hate relationship with folders, and sometimes they map to the physical folder, and sometimes they... just don't.

So - what can I use them for?  Is there a good use case beyond just logically grouping files in a project to organize things a bit?

---

**Oh!** And one time I opened a folder from my drive directly in Visual Studio, and it showed up just like a solution - but it was just an open folder... it was kinda weird.  What's up with that?

---

### Links to Info

This Q&A **([Actual folders in Visual Solution Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468027/actual-folders-in-visual-solution-explorer?rq=1))** explains some more about how to keep folders in a solution mapped to the physical folders, which VS is very picky about and doesn't even try to keep in sync...

Comment: Isn't "just logically grouping things" the use case for all folders everywhere, both virtual and physical?

Comment: @David Certainly it could be I just feel like I'm missing something, but I'm not.  That would make a good "negative" answer.  :)

Comment: Solution folders are virtual, project folders are not.

Comment: @KiwiPiet Okay - so why would I want to use (or want to avoid) one or the other then?  Sounds like the start to a good answer.

Comment: I guess I found the real "alternative" I was looking for here today.  In the case of Solutions/Projects which are not Visual Studio based, you can just open the folders directly.  For example, I downloaded a repo at work that is Linux-based and just to view it, I was able to open the folder hierarchy directly in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Visual Studio virtual folders is a stupid idea, just ask xCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there is essentially two most common uses for folders within your solution/project.

First and probably most obvious, folders are used to organize and group together relevant files. While this is more of a personal preference thing - I often use folders to organize my code similar to that of MVC (Model View Controller).

Second and usually less common but still something to be familiar with are folders that get copied into the output directory. These folders get created when you have a file with its advanced property **Copy to Output Directory** set to ***Copy always*** or ***Copy if newer***. These files then become a part of the *Build Action* - upon building your solution, these files get copied to the output directory. This is used when there is a need for certain files within your solution such as a data file or external resource needed to interact with.

**Example:** I recently worked on a project that required my solution to interact with PhantomJs, which is an external standalone executable. I needed my code to make calls and pass data to this application - thus making it a vital part of my solution. PhantomJs was placed in a folder and set to *Copy if newer* which ensured my copy of the executable was an available resource during runtime.

Comment: Thanks. What would be an example of a file you would have copied to an output directory?  Like a configuration file or readme.txt that you wanted to distribute with the other build files?

Comment: No problem, please see my updates for more info and a real world example.